# Trying to upload an image on imgur in c# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, imgur

I'm new to C# and i am doing an app using the imgurAPI.
I'm trying to upload an image on it but it seems that there is a problem while reading the file. Don't know really what to do.
(the error don't come from Oauth, or access token etc)

Here are the functiosn that i use. The first one is the one called when clicking on the uploading button.

```
public async void FileNameButton_Click()
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ICI");
            FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");

            StorageFile file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {

                _path = file.Path;
                await UploadImage();
                Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

_

```
public async Task UploadImage()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("UPLOADIMAGE");
        try
        {
            if (_path != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("String to upload " + _path); 
                //_path is ok here, form is         "C:\Users\MyName\Pictures\1412091183-dreamfall-chapters.jpg"

                var endpoint = new ImageEndpoint(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ImgurApi>()._Client);
                try
                {
                    var file = File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
                    var image = await endpoint.UploadImageBinaryAsync(file);
                }
                catch (Exception message)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Imgur.API.ImgurException imgurEx)
        {
            Debug.Write("An error occurred uploading an image to Imgur.");
            Debug.Write(imgurEx.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here are the errors i get :

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.IO.FileSystem.dll System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous
>   operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider
>   wrapping this method in Task.Run.    at
>   System.IO.WinRTFileSystem.EnsureBackgroundThread()    at
>   System.IO.WinRTFileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
>   options, FileStream parent)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path)    at
>   Epicture.ViewModels.MainPageVm.d__19.MoveNext()
>   C:\Users\Bandini\Pictures\1412091183-dreamfall-chapters.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you 'Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run' ? Since it seams that you are locking the main UI thread. One of 2 most important rules of what not to do.

Comment: No i don't really understand what wrapping this method in Task.Run mean. What's the other rules?

Comment: I did this await Task.Run(() => UploadImage()); Is this the good way for Task wrapping ? it seems to do the work, now i just have an access denied on my path.

Comment: access denied when you upload the image to imgur or when you're reading the image ?

Comment: when i'm reading the image. (i check read-only on my folder etc etc, i think my app don't have the right to)

Comment: Try looking at stack overflow or googling c# file read access denied. There seems to be multiple reasons why this is happening. I'll have some time in ~8 hours so if you'll still be stuck i'll try to find the reason behind this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Stralos. I "solved" the  problem. It works when i launch my program on Release but not in Debug mode with visual studio

Comment: Do you run your visual studio in administrator mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `File.ReadAllBytes`, which is a synchronous call and will block UI thread.

You should use aync IO APIs for this.

Also ImageEndpoint has a method that accepts stream, which is preferable.

example:

```
using(var file = File.OpenRead(_path))
{
    var image = await endpoint.UploadImageStreamAsync(file);
}
```